# Is this IP ownership provision too vaguge?

Tags: intellectual-property, canada

Is this Intellectual Property provision that is found in an employment agreement too general? To my understanding things like "formulas" or "know-how" aren't protected by IP law. (For example if I experience that the bank that the company took a loan out of has poor customer service, I can use this information in my decision to avoid doing business with the bank in the future). The terms "processes" and "procedures" is very vague. Where is the line normally drawn when it comes to enforcing IP ownership rights?

This literally is saying "any attempt to use intellectual property would be a breach of your obligations". I'm assuming it means to say any attempt to use it outside the workplace would be a breach. Am I understanding this correctly?

> You are advised of your obligation in relation to any intellectual
> property or work product that may be developed by you in the course of
> your employment. The law is clear that any intellectual property
> developed by an employee is owned by the employer, and therefore any
> intellectual property such as code or script or other workplace
> intellectual property developed by you in the course of employment is
> owned by the Company. Any attempts to take the intellectual property
> and use it or sell it would be a breach of your obligations.
>
> Intellectual property means: the result of intellectual or artistic
> activity, created by you in a scholarly, professional or student
> capacity that can be owned by a person. Specifically this includes
> inventions, publications, educational materials,samples, databases,
> articles, graphs, code, processes, procedures, techniques, know-how,
> formulae. as well as other intellectual property rights (creations)
> that can protected under legislation but not limited to patent,
> copyright or trade-mark, industrial design laws and/or through a trade
> secret.